# Delete data in sql table using c# and present it in gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following method:

```
   Connection c =new Connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    String empID = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblEmployee WHERE employeeNumber='empID'";
    cmd.Connection = c.con;
    c.con.Open();
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
    int numberDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(numberDeleted.ToString() + " employees were deleted.<br>");
    c.con.Close();
```

I'm trying to delete a record in the table and update gridview to show the remaining records in the table. the code doesn't delete any record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
DELETE FROM tblEmployee WHERE employeeNumber='empID'
```

Should be converted to use a parametrized query in the following way:

```
cmd.CommandText="DELETE FROM tblEmployee WHERE employeeNumber=@id";
```

The reason is that your previous statement was simply concatenating the `delete from ...` part with the string `'empid'` which I assume is not what you want. You are after something like this:

`delete from ... where employeeNumber={some_number}` where `some_number` is a *parameter*

In order to pass a parameter to your SQL Statement you do this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",empID);//I assume empID is a variable containing an ID
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you want the change immediately reflected on your grid, you need to select the data again and rebind your grid.

Comment: This answer would be better with a quick explanation of what's going on in the suggested code.

Comment: @Michelle will add more details.

Comment: Thank's it workes, But can you also tell me how to update my gridview ?

Comment: @user2023203 how do you bind the data to your gridview? Show the code and I'll be able to help further.

Comment: @Icarus, I'm not sure how  to be honest. what code are you looking for?

Comment: @user2023203 Do you use a SQLDataSource to bind your data? Show the markup for the gridview...

Comment: I'm not using SQLDataSource because i can;t use .Bind(), so I really don't know how to bind the data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34772/discussion-between-user2023203-and-icarus)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that probably no empID with the value 'empID' exists..

You didn't put the value of the empID in the command, but added an exact string of 'empID', which cannot be found in your table.
Put the empID value as a parameter like Icarus advised.

Comment: **You should never concatenate a user-supplied value in an SQL query.** This opens you up to SQL injection attacks. The correct way to include values in a query is to add a parameter.

Comment: Michelle i know that, but adding a parameter in an SQLCOmmand is still a type of concatenation. I was only pointing out that he was searching for an id with a value of 'empID'.

Comment: It's not "a type of concatenation". Google "C sharp string concatenation" and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx), accurately describing string concatenation - the exact thing OP **shouldn't** do, is the first result. "Concatenate the command text with the value" is absolutely the wrong way to describe the solution to this problem.

Comment: Well pardon my english, i will change the anwser to improve the correct meaning so noone else needs to stuble upon the exact meaning.
My point was different of what you're so eager to stuble at.

Comment: If your answer is "do what the other answer says," it's probably best to just delete it.